# installation of doctrine orm

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a problem when installing symfony/orm-pack

```
PS D:\TRABAJOOOOOOOOOOOO\Proyecto\APIPrueba> composer require symfony/orm-pack
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update symfony/orm-pack
Loading composer repositories with package information
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "5.4.*"
Updating dependencies
Lock file operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Locking symfony/orm-pack (v2.4.0)
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing symfony/orm-pack (v2.4.0): Extracting archive
Generating optimized autoload files
46 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!

Run composer recipes at any time to see the status of your Symfony recipes.

Unpacking Symfony packs
  - Unpacked symfony/orm-pack
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 0 updates, 1 removal
  - Removing symfony/orm-pack (v2.4.0)
Generating optimized autoload files
45 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!

Run composer recipes at any time to see the status of your Symfony recipes.

Executing script cache:clear [OK]
Executing script assets:install public [OK]

No security vulnerability advisories found.

No security vulnerability advisories found.
```

Why do you install it and then remove it?

composer require symfony/orm-pack

This is how I'm installing it